# Gem Pry - NameError: uninitialized constant Pry::BondCompleter::Bond

Tags: rubygems, pry

Whenever I type pry in my commandline, it opens up with this error.

```
    terminal$ pry
    NameError: uninitialized constant Pry::BondCompleter::Bond
    from /home/think/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/pry-0.9.12.5/lib/pry/completion.rb:26:in `start'
    [1] pry(main)>
```

What is the fix? Even I start guard, this shows up,

```
terminal$ guard
18:07:44 - INFO - Guard is using NotifySend to send notifications.
18:07:44 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
18:07:44 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
18:07:44 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
18:07:44 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
18:07:44 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/home/think/jonathan/organizor'
NameError: uninitialized constant Pry::BondCompleter::Bond
from /home/think/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/pry-0.9.12.5/lib/pry/completion.rb:26:in `start'
[1] guard(main)>
```

Is there anything we could do??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be a problem in version 0.9.12.5

```
gem uninstall pry -v 0.9.12.5
gem install pry -v 0.9.12.4
```

fixed it for me. For your Gemfile:

```
gem 'pry', '0.9.12.6'
```

Comment: Version 0.9.12.6 (released a couple of hours after 0.9.12.5) fixes the problem, so: `gem update pry`

Answer (score 1):

Update to the latest version (0.9.12.6 as of writing). That fixed the problem for me.

For completeness, here is the GitHub [issue #1106](https://github.com/pry/pry/issues/1106).